# Django: Creating a colour filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-filter

I want to create a filter that returns all products that contain a specific colour.

I am using the django-filter package. I can achieve the desired results using a charfilter and entering the colour I want to search.

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    colour = django_filters.filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['colour']
```

Is there a way I can create a dropdown filter with static colour options(e.g. 'blue', 'red', 'green') which will return any products with that colour. So if I have a product who's colour is 'red/green', selecting option red will return that product.

Comment: How is the `colour` stored in the database? As a simple `CharField`?

Comment: Yes the colour is stored as a charfield - colour = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you think this is the best way to store it?